# Getting path around triangles

Tags: algorithm

I got a list of triangles in a triangular grid like this:

```
__________________
/\      /\      /\
  \    /  \    /
   \  /    \  /
____\/______\/____
    /\      /\
   /  \    /  \
  /    \  /    \
\/______\/______\/
/\      /\      /\
  \    /  \    /
   \  /    \  /
____\/______\/____
```

A triangle can either be present or not. I need to get a path around the triangles like:

```
 ========
\\      /\\
 \\    /  \\
  \\  /    \\
   \\/______\\========
    \\      /\      //
     \\    /  \    //
      \\  /    \  //
       \\/======\//
```

I need to get the bold lines in clockwise order around the triangles. What algorithm can I use to get this? I can already classify triangles into groups using disjoint set, but I have no idea how to get the path around a group.

Comment: How are the triangles represented programatically?

Comment: you need a path between all the present triangles?

Comment: @EvilTeach: A 2 dimensional array of bools.

Comment: @Simone: no, I need a path around all triangles that touch each other. I know how to split all triangles into groups that touch each other, and I need the path around each of these groups separately (you can consider only one group for sake of the example).

Comment: So each element in the array is a point, that may or may not be a vertex of a triangle?  true if it is, false if it is not?

Comment: @EvilTeach, no. each point is a center of a triangle (if you check they are lined up in rectangular grid), true if there is a triangle there, false otherwise.

Comment: Are the triangles grouped together or are there islands of trangles to be dealt with?

Comment: @EvilTeach: there are islands, but I already know how to separate them, so you can assume they are all grouped together.

Comment: @Dani: there are 2 types of triangles: V and ^. How do you distinguisg them in your triangle array? Say you have only 1 triangle. Then the appearance of the boundary line depends on the triangle shape.

Comment: @Jiri: The shape is `^` if `(x % 2 == 0) ^ (y % 2 == 0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An isolated triangle has three lines round it. If you add another triangle beside it, you lose one line where they merge, and gain two others from the new triangle. So you can keep track of the set of lines that appear as boundaries to a group of triangles placed beside each other, and you can also keep track of which of these lines meet which other lines.

I am assuming here that only sharing a boundary joins two triangles in a group, and not sharing a point. Lines meet at a point, and if only sharing a boundary counts as joining two triangles, then each outer line is connected with just one other outer line at each of its ends.

If you follow (e.g. with depth first search) the graph formed where nodes are lines and links between lines show where a line is adjacent to another line, you will trace a cycle of lines - it can't be more complicated than that because any single line meets at most two other lines, one at each of its end points.

If your group of triangles has no holes inside it you will then retrieve a single cycle which is its outer boundary. If the group of triangles has holes in it you will retrieve the outer boundary and a cycle for each of the holes. The outer boundary must be the cycle that contains the largest area, because it contains all of the holes.

Comment: Any idea how can I address the lines to know if a line already exists?

Comment: Since you are keeping track of triangles, I would associate each line with the higher of the two triangles it joins. That means that each V-shaped triangle owns two lines, and each A-shaped trangle owns one line. If you don't mind that there are some holes in the numbering sequence, you could just number each line by shifting its triangle number left by one and then adding 0 or 1 as the low order bit if it is owned by a V-shaped triangle.

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through each triangle and for each side of the triangle check if it touch another triangle; if not just make the side bold.

EDIT

if you need an animation that display the lines drawing in a clockwise manner, just compute all the sides to be drawn and then sort the lines by polar angle and display it in this order

Comment: i think i miss the clockwise requirement..it's required an user to see the lines drawing while it's happening?

Comment: its required so I can draw the bold lines properly.

Comment: you're right; but i think i'm on the right track, we only need the correct sorting algo

Comment: it's actually easier than you think; after you've found all the side segments, just start from one of them and found the other segment that share a vertex with it and continue this way

Comment: its easy to say, but to find a line by its vertexes means I need to use another data structure and more memory (which I'm already short of)

Comment: but this is the easiest and fastest way...you don't necessarly need a memory expensive hash look up; i think it's sufficient a binary tree; and moreover you only need to do this for the segments of the hull